# How to use NOT IN correctly in a WFS CQL attribute filter?

Tags: qgis, wfs, cql-filter, qgis-2.16

I am using a WFS of road centrelines available [here](https://data.linz.govt.nz/layer/329-nz-road-centerlines-topo-150k/webservices/) for a small mapping project in QGIS. There are a number of features in my area of interest that I just want to exclude. I figured that an attribute filter might be the easiest way to achieve this.

In the query builder dialogue within the layer properties, I added the following filter:

`"t50_fid" NOT IN (3324565)`

Although the "Test" button tells me that the where clause manages to return *n – 1* rows, when I close the dialogue the layer fails to load, with the following exception logged:

> Layer NZ Road Centerlines (Topo, 1:50k): Download of features for
>   layer data.linz.govt.nz:layer-329 failed or partially failed: Server
>   generated an exception in GetFeature response:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXException: Attempted to construct illegal filter - I
>   dont understand the tag: fes:ValueReference. HINT: tags are
>   case-sensitive! Attempted to construct illegal filter - I dont
>   understand the tag: fes:ValueReference. HINT: tags are
>   case-sensitive!. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5

So the `NOT IN` clause seems to construct an invalid CQL filter, with the layer source that is produced looking like so:

`filter='"t50_fid" NOT IN (3324565)' retrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:2193' typename='data.linz.govt.nz:layer-329' url='https://data.linz.govt.nz/services;key=*MYKEY*/wfs?' version='auto' table="" sql=`

The following filter does work successfully, but the cost is that the syntax is harder to use if I want to exclude a longer list of features.

`"t50_fid" != 3324565` (OK for one feature)

`"t50_fid" != 3324565 AND "t50_fid" != 3324566 AND ...` (gets cumbersome quickly, and hard to adjust).

This style of filter produces the following layer source:

`filter='"t50_fid" != 3324565' retrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:2193' typename='data.linz.govt.nz:layer-329' url='https://data.linz.govt.nz/services;key=*MYKEY*/wfs?' version='auto' table="" sql=`

Incidentally, I figured that maybe my use of `NOT IN` is incorrect. `"t50_fid" NOT IN (3324565,)` causes no exception or warning, but fails to filter anything. `"t50_fid" NOT IN [3324565]` has an identical result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can successfully use the `NOT IN` syntax if you are filtering more than one feature.

`"attribute" NOT IN (1, 2)` ← works

`"attribute" NOT IN (1)` ← does not work

So I suppose this syntax is limited to filtering based on arrays of length greater than 1. However you can work around this if you still want to with:

`"attribute" NOT IN (1, 1)` ← works

In my case: `"t50_fid" NOT IN (3324565, 3324565)`.

I find this behaviour a little strange and I think it smells like a bug, but that is a workaround.